# Change the shape of an array using another array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape one array using other array.

Say I have `array_1`, whose `shape` is `(5, 1)`, e.g.:

```
>>> array_1
array([[ 0.33333333],
       [ 0.36666667],
       [ 0.16666667],
       [ 0.06666667],
       [ 0.06666667]]
```

and `array_2`, whose shape is `(1, 5)`. I want to reshape `array_1` so that it gets the shape of `array_2`. The shape of `array_2` can change every time I run the code.

Comment: Are these numpy arrays ?

Comment: yes.i have added an example array in the question.

Comment: @AnandSKumar thanks for undoing that work...

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry but had to roll back because the example got removed.

Comment: @AnandSKumar no, you didn't; you could have done what I just did, i.e. edit the example into the improved post

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was editing your changes into it, while you edited it.

Comment: @AnandSKumar that seems like an inefficient way around to do things!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `numpy` arrays, just use `array_1.reshape(array_2.shape)`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.arange(5).reshape(5, 1)
>>> arr2 = np.arange(5, 10).reshape(1, 5)
>>> arr1
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> arr2
array([[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> arr1.reshape(arr2.shape)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> arr2.reshape(arr1.shape)
array([[5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```

Note that this is not in-place; it creates a new array, so you would need to assign e.g. `array_1 = array_1.reshape(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You simply should use `numpy.transpose` in this case:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = [[ 0.33333333],
 [ 0.36666667],
 [ 0.16666667],
 [ 0.06666667],
 [ 0.06666667]]

print "Shape of original array_1: ", np.shape(array_1)

array_1 = np.transpose(array_1)

print array_1
print "Shape of transposed array_1: ", np.shape(array_1)
```

**Output:**

```
Shape of original array_1:  (5, 1)
[[ 0.33333333  0.36666667  0.16666667  0.06666667  0.06666667]]
Shape of transposed array_1:  (1, 5)
```